# Would a 1.5 layover in Dublin airport from Toronto on my way to London be risky?

Tags: air-travel, airports, layovers, dublin

I am traveling from Toronto to London via Dublin. I am booking the connecting flights myself, so I arrive in with West Jet and fly out with RyanAir.
My flight arrives in at 08:45. There is a flight to London at 11.05. Would it be risky to book this?
Would I need to go through security again or not?
Alternatively, there is a flight at 12:55 but I don't want to be hanging around for a long time at the airport.
All advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Will you have checked bags? Or only hand luggage?

Comment: Which country's passport will you be using?

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be risky to book this?

Yes.

> Would I need to go through security again or not?

Yes. You need to do clear immigration, pick up your bags, go through custom, drop your bags again and re-enter through security.

> Alternatively, there is a flight at 12:55

I would go with that. Personally my minimum for a self connection is 4 hours.

This all boils down to a risk/reward analysis. In this case the risk is probably "tolerable". If you miss the connection, you loose the Ryan Air ticket but it's still early in the day and there are probably 15+ more flights you can take that day unless you need to be at a specific airport in London (London has 5). Prices for tomorrow are anywhere between $130 and $250.

The risk is also impacted by a number of factors

1. What's your passport ?
2. Do you have checked luggage ?
3. What's your class of service?
4. Do you have status with any airline ?
5. Do you need to be at a specific airport in London and do you need to be there before a specific time ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Dublin airport website:

> We advise you allow 2.5 hours for a short-haul flight departure time, and 3.5 hours for a long-haul flight departure time. If you are checking in a bag, please allow up to an hour of additional time.

Source: https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information/connections/self-connecting-passengers

Answer (score 0):

It’s fairly risky, yes. You can’t transfer airside; you’ll have to clear immigration and then security, which has been quite slow recently in Dublin. Nevertheless, that Ryanair ticket cannot have cost you that much, and there are plenty of flights to London (or, for Ryanair, “London”) throughout the day. So if you risk it and lose, it won’t cost you too much time or money.

Comment: Same day tickets are rather expensive or even sold out.

Comment: @Anders You're incorrect; there really is a lot of availability there, and market forces apply to same-day tickets as well as any others. To give an example, even as we speak, there are DUB-LHR tickets available for half a dozen different departures today for about 75 quid.

Comment: You may have to change to a different airline for cheaper tickets.

Comment: @Willeke Yep, Aer Lingus is (IME) better for last-minute fairs out of Dublin than RyanAir; BA is something of a wildcard.

Comment: If you know early enough that you may want a certain flight, it may well be cheaper to buy two tickets for different flights while they are at their lowest and use just one. If you miss the first flight you have the second ticket.